# Is there a way to use conditionals on colors in a scatter plot in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

So Im new in the field of data science, the thing is I have a dataset practice with so what Im trying to do is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('datasets/office_episodes.csv')

x = np.array(file.loc[:,'episode_number'])

y = np.array(file.loc[:, 'viewership_mil'])

scaled_ratings = np.array(file.loc[:, 'scaled_ratings'])

ratings2 = list(scaled_ratings)
   
plt.title("Popularity, Quality, and Guest Appearances on the Office")

plt.xlabel("Episode Number")

plt.ylabel("Viewership (Millions)")

for i in ratings2:
    if i < 0.25:
         plt.scatter(x, y, c='red')
    elif i >=0.25 and i < 0.50:
          plt.scatter(x, y, c='orange')   
    elif i >= 0.50 and i < 0.75:
        plt.scatter(x, y, c='lightgreen')
    elif i >= 0.75:
        plt.scatter(x, y, c='darkgreen')
    else:
        plt.scatter(x, y, c='pink')


plt.show()
```

As you can see in the **for loop** Im conditioning the colors of the dots in the scatter plot based on the scale ratings but when plot is displayed it looks like this:

[image]

I also tried to create a variable called *ratings3* that contains ratings2, so in that way I could make a list comprehension so in that I could pass *ratings3* in the color paramater of the **plt.scatter(**) function.

Comment: Use pd.cut to create categories, then plot color based on category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sample data and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 175
np.random.seed(15)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'episode_number': np.random.randint(0, 180, n),
    'viewership_mil': np.random.randint(2_500_000, 12_500_000, n) / 1_000_000
})
df['scaled_ratings'] = df['viewership_mil'] / df['viewership_mil'].sum() * 100
```

`df.head()`:

```
   episode_number  viewership_mil  scaled_ratings
0             140       12.414172        0.925457
1             133        9.918293        0.739393
2             119        7.513288        0.560104
3             128       11.664907        0.869600
4             156        8.610445        0.641895
```

Create categories based on `scaled_ratings` using [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut):

```
colors = pd.cut(
    df['scaled_ratings'],
    bins=[np.NINF, 0.25, .5, .75, np.inf],
    labels=['red', 'orange', 'lightgreen', 'darkgreen'],
    right=False
)
```

`colors.head()`:

```
0       darkgreen
1      lightgreen
2      lightgreen
3       darkgreen
4      lightgreen
```

Then plot [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) and specify `c=`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x=df['episode_number'], y=df['viewership_mil'], c=colors)
plt.title("Popularity, Quality, and Guest Appearances on the Office")
plt.xlabel("Episode Number")
plt.ylabel("Viewership (Millions)")
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1]

---

All together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 175
np.random.seed(15)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'episode_number': np.random.randint(0, 180, n),
    'viewership_mil': np.random.randint(2_500_000, 12_500_000, n) / 1_000_000
})
df['scaled_ratings'] = df['viewership_mil'] / df['viewership_mil'].sum() * 100

# Assign Colors based on df['scaled_ratings']
colors = pd.cut(
    df['scaled_ratings'],
    bins=[np.NINF, 0.25, .5, .75, np.inf],
    labels=['red', 'orange', 'lightgreen', 'darkgreen'],
    right=False  # Lower-bound inclusive x >= .25 and x < .5
)
# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x=df['episode_number'], y=df['viewership_mil'], c=colors)
plt.title("Popularity, Quality, and Guest Appearances on the Office")
plt.xlabel("Episode Number")
plt.ylabel("Viewership (Millions)")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert at this, but here is my solution. You would first have to make separate arrays for each category. Then you can plot each with the chosen colors.

```
y1 = np.array(file.loc[file['scaled_ratings'] < 0.25, 'viewership_mil'])
y2 = np.array(file.loc[0.25 <= file['scaled_ratings'] < 0.5, 'viewership_mil'])
y3 = np.array(file.loc[0.5 <= file['scaled_ratings'] < 0.75, 'viewership_mil'])
y4 = np.array(file.loc[0.75 <= file['scaled_ratings'], 'viewership_mil'])

plt.scatter(x, y1, c='red')
plt.scatter(x, y2, c='orange')
plt.scatter(x, y3, c='lightgreen')
plt.scatter(x, y4, c='darkgreen')
```